# Detect time settings of device (iOS) from Xamarin Forms

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, time-format

I'm looking for a solution to detect the date settings for iOS from xamrin. here is the problem statement : I have a label(timelabel) in application where it is binding to current time. When user changes the time settings in device to 24-hr / 12-hr format or vice versa. I was not able to detect the changes and the timelabel in my Xamarin app is always showing in same format of time.

Can anyone have Idea how to change time format according to the device time format set by the user in device settings?

Thanks,

Comment: I think you'd be better off using iOS's built in time formatting options (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html) than trying to detect the user's preferences and coming up with your own formatter. Apple has implemented date and time formatting so it's possible to use the user's time format preferences, locale, and other settings.

Comment: As @DylanS says, when formatting a date iOS uses by default the user's settings if you don't specify a format. (Which means you should always use a format when formatting dates for your data). Not sure if this behavior was copied to Xamarin's DateTime but easy enough to try. If not, use Dylan's tips to let iOS SDK format the date for use (NSDate & NSDateFormatter)